# Change event does not propagate from Backbone Collection to Backbone Model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Backbone Model that has Backbone Collections for some of its attributes.

When a change event is triggered on one of these collections, it does not propagate to the parent model.

Is it possible to change this, so that the event does propagate?

Comment: It's the other way round, model change events trigger collection change event. If you don't like the way answer by metadept is the solution

Answer (score 3):

Provided you're not referencing a collection that the model's part of (which would create circular logic), you should be able to bind it explicitly:

```
model.listenTo(model.collection, 'change', function() {
        model.trigger('change');
    });
```

Here's a jsFiddle that seems to be working: http://jsfiddle.net/2Nctk/2/

Comment: Are you sure about the `model.trigger('change')` part?

Comment: `model.trigger('change')` will trigger the event right there and return `model`, `model` is then pass as the callback to `listenTo`. You need a function wrapper and you probably want to check the [arguments that go with a `"change"` event](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog).

Comment: @muistooshort Seems to work when it's wrapped in a function (took me awhile to set up my jsFiddle tolerably). Thanks for the insight.